# How to save a set of things over and over (autosave)

Tags: ajax, django, formset

I am creating a **set of things** (each thing has FK to the set) directly with forms. The problem I am having is with the view(s).

I want to create the **set** for the **things** and then update all the **things** over and over using AJAX (Kind of like autosave). In my case the set is a `SurveySet` and the thing is a `Survey`.

```
def screen_many(request):

    if not request.is_ajax():

        # get an ordered QuerySet of students
        students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items())
        e_students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items(), 'e')
        i_students = ids_to_students(request.GET.items(), 'i')
        survey_count = len(students)

        # Build a dataset of students with there associated behavior types.
        data =  [{'student':s.pk, 'behavior_type': 'E'} for s in e_students]
        data += [{'student':s.pk, 'behavior_type': 'I'} for s in i_students]

        # Use that dataset as initial data for a formset
        SurveyFormset = formset_factory(SurveyForm, extra=0)
        survey_formset = SurveyFormset(initial=data)

        # ... not shown: customizing the crispy form helper

        # Make a new survey set...
        ss = SurveySet()
        ss.user=request.user
        ss.save()

    if request.is_ajax():
        surveyset = get_object_or_404(SurveySet, pk=ss.pk)
        surveys = surveyset.survey_set.all()

        survey_formset = SurveyFormset(request.POST, instance=surveyset)
        if survey_formset.is_valid():
            # Create surveys for this surveyset
            for form in survey_formset.forms:
                saved = form.save(commit=False)
                saved.surveyset = ss
                saved.save()

        HttpResponse('saved.')


    formsetWithStudents = zip(survey_formset.forms, students)

    c = {
         'formsetWithStudents' : formsetWithStudents,
         'students' : students,
         'survey_count' : survey_count,
         'e_students': e_students,
         'i_students': i_students,
         'survey_formset': survey_formset,
        }
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response("reports/screen_many.html", c)
```

If my URL looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/screen_many/?e_1=13&e_2=12&i_1=14` The view makes 3 survey sets all the while complaining that there is an

`UnboundLocalError at /screen_many/
local variable 'ss' referenced before assignment`

I feel like I need to make a separate view just for the ajax and I want the SurveySet object to only be created once.

So, in other words. I am filling in forms of a formset which update after clicking "view next form" This is in my template.

```
    $('.next').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide()
        $(this).parent().next().show()

        var posting = $.post('/screen_many/', $('form').serializeArray() );

        posting.done(function(response){
            console.log(response)
    });
```

Or I could send the POST data here:

```
def save_as_you_go(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        # Get the surveyset from POST
        ss = request.POST['form-0-surveyset']
        surveyset = get_object_or_404(SurveySet, pk=ss)
        surveys = surveyset.survey_set.all()
        SurveyFormSet = inlineformset_factory(SurveySet, Survey, form=SurveyForm, can_delete=False, extra=0)
        survey_formset = SurveyFormSet(request.POST, instance=surveyset)

        if survey_formset.is_valid():
            for form in survey_formset.forms:
                student = form.save(commit=False)
                student.surveyset = surveyset
                student.save()
        return HttpResponse('saved.')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

But then I get

```
[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if my answer seems naive--I am new to Python and Django, but it looks like you are setting the ss variable in the non-ajax request and then referencing it in the ajax request. Perhaps you can set ss prior to the if statements?

```
    #set ss variable before if statements
    ss = SurveySet()
    ss.user=request.user
    ss.save()

    if not request.is_ajax():
    ###do your non-ajax request stuff
    if request.is_ajax():
    ###do your ajax request stuff
```

Comment: This will make the error go away, but then every time I try to update a thing in the set it will create a whole new set full of the same things each time. If my URL looks like this: http://127.0.0.1:8000/screen_many/?e_1=13&e_2=12&i_1=14 The view makes 3 survey sets, because I use the same view for AJAX.